# binding.pry appears to be debouncing and then re-displaying text input

Tags: ruby, pry

I'm following along with a tutorial book, and in order to step through my code I've required `pry` and added a `binding.pry` reference in a method which gets executed:

```
require 'pry'

module Rulers
  module Model
    class FileModel
      def initialize(filename)
        @filename = filename
        binding.pry
        basename = File.split(filename)[-1]
...
```

When I load the code which executes this constructor method, I successfully hit my `binding.pry` debugger point as expected.  However, when I start typing commands at the prompt, the characters I enter are printed out in the same prompt:

```
[7] pry(#<Rulers::Model::FileModel>)> .whic.whichh
```

In the above example, I typed `.which`.  I had gotten all the way to `.whic` when the REPL added the characters I had typed thus far (i.e. it added `.whic` to `.whic`, resulting in `.whic.whic`).  The last character I typed was `h`, which registers after `.whic.whic`.  Finally, the last `h` I typed was also appended to the chars on the prompt.

Interestingly, the duplicated chars do not appear to affect the REPL's ability to understand the commands I type in.  For example, the following:

```
[8] pry(#<Rulers::Model::FileModel>)> .which .which vim
[8] pry(#<Rulers::Model::FileModel>)> .which vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

In the above example, I was successful in typing `.which`  quickly enough to not result in a muddled version of the `which` command, and I also pressed `Enter` before `vim` could be duplicated erroneously.  If the redundant 2nd `.which` command were to affect my ability to return the expected output, I would expect to see an error returned.  Instead, I see `/usr/bin/vim` as I would expect when typing `which vim` in my regular, non-`pry` command line prompt.

I have no theories on where to begin debugging this.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have seen this before. Is this breakpoint happening during a request, by chance? I think it might have to do with the web server being multithreaded but not 100% sure. You can also try `byebug` debugger and see if it has the same issue.

Comment: What environment is this run in? What exactly is the tutorial? Max is on the right track here I think. This can happen if another thread or process is reading the tty you are working on at the same time. It can also happen with Rails if Spring is used to speed up reloading, as Spring does some funky stuff with the tty. In that case remove Spring from your Gemfile and try again.

Comment: @Casper this is run on my local machine, in the `:development` environment, using the "Rebuilding Rails" tutorial.  The app runs a simple WEBrick server, executed using `bundle exec rerun -- rackup -p 3001`.

Comment: And you do not have Spring in your Gemfile? To reduce moving parts I would also run it without `rerun`, just to make sure you can eliminate as many parts as possible which could be causing the issue.

Comment: No Spring in the Gemfile.  Funnily enough, your suggestion to remove the `rerun` reference seems to have done the trick!  I removed it and restarted the server with a simple `bundle exec rackup -p 3001` and things seemed to work fine even over a significant length of time.  Then I killed the server and restarted it with `rerun` prepended again, and the problem re-appeared.